# Date strptime returns invalid date

Tags: ruby, irb

Here is my IRB session

```
1.9.2p290 :020 > Date.strptime("31-2-2010", "%d-%m-%Y")
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

I have given the proper values, yet it is returning `ArgumentError`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,  you are missing something:
There are never 31 days in February, regardless of the year.

You have given it an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Time.strptime("31-2-2010", "%d-%m-%Y")` would give you `2010-03-03 00:00:00 +0000`.

I use `Time.strptime("31-2-2010", "%d-%m-%Y").to_date` to avoid invalid date errors.